# How to set a width to a Kendo UI Autocomplete control

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, autocomplete, kendo-ui

I am using the kendo ui autocomplete control inside a div. I set the styles for the div but it  didn't work for me.

```
<div>

@(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
.Name("NameAutoComplete") 
.DataTextField("FullName") 
.BindTo(Model.NameList)  
.Filter("contains") 
)

</div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: in the telerik controls for mvc there was `.HTMLAttributes` do see somehthing of the sort in kendo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed the easiest way is to do it through the HtmlAttributes method.

e.g.

```
@(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete().Name("test").HtmlAttributes(new { style="width:400px"}))
```